# How to identify brand for specific NDC in Prescrible Rxnorm data file?

Tags: product, medical, nlm

please help me to find brand and package details for a specific NDC in the rxnorm data file. I've downloaded the free rxnorm_full_prescribe data file from https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/docs/rxnormfiles.html site.
I can find some data from the RXNSAT file such as form, strength, labeler, drug name, and brand type.
But I couldn't find the brand info by NDC or RXCUI ID.

For example, 24338085310 has 1425337 as Rxcui id.
I'm unable to find the brand for this NDC.
But that corresponding brand is available in the RXNCONCO file it has a different rxcui.
How to map or identify if this NDC belongs to this Brand?